# i got stuck on JAVA

Tags: java

im a begginer of programming from yesterday, and i got huge stuck on java

hangeul which is look unfamiliar characters are not important, what i really wanna know is `SC.CLOSe` <- this one `(error:unreachable code)` . i tried to find out what the problem is on internet,but there wasnt the same one who did it ,before. plz help me

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class switch문연습 {

    private static int number;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = sc.nextInt();

        /*지금 내가 할려는 건, 스위치문과 스캐너를 이용해서 처음에 이색데이트 
        라는 문장이 뜨면 거기서 케이스들(어떤종류가 있는지)을 보여주고
        그것을 선택했을때 고려해야하는 여러가지를 다시 케이스로 나뉘어서
        들어갈수있도록 만드는 거미줄같은것을 만들것임*/
        int a = number;
        switch(i = a) {

        case (1):
            System.out.println("무작위 지하철 노선도 뽑기"); 
            break;
        case (2):
            System.out.println("남산데이트");
            break;
        case (3):
            System.out.println("심리카페");
            break;
        case (4):
            System.out.println("셀프 공방-쥬얼리");
            break;
        case (5):
            System.out.println("향수제작");
            break;
        case (6):
            System.out.println("VAR게임체험");
            break;
        case (7):
            System.out.println("만화카페");
            break;
            sc.close();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: and there is a minor error on -> Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);  <- this phrase like 'resource leak 'sc' is never closed '

Comment: The call to sc.close() is unreachable because it was preceded by a break in your switch block.

Comment: java compiler tells you that "sc.close()" will never get executed. It is indeed outside of any case

Comment: yall means delete the 'break;'?   then how can i make program more complicated?  my original plan was that if someone click the cases then can see more cases and like that like normal app

Comment: Terrible title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: Fix the broken Shift key on your keyboard. This is not a casual chat room.

Answer (score 4):

`sc.close();` is located right after a `break;` statement. The `break` will interrupt the control flow and end the `switch` statement meaning that no other line of code in the `switch` will be executed.

Edit:
Following @dan1st comment, you have to move your `sc.close();` after the `switch` (more info in his comment)

Comment: `sc.close` should be located after the `switch` statement or within a finally. try-with-resources is another good possibility.

Comment: You are absolutely right ! Post the answer and I'll upvote you sir !

Comment: It is not really an answer. It is an improvement to your answer.